# eval black magic loses scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eval, es6-promise

***disclaimer*** I do not endorse the use of eval, and I do not use it when I write code.

I am forking logic on a legacy project and came across some very odd behavior with eval and would like to know an under the hood explanation of why this behavior exists.

```
var baz = function(cb) {
    cb('asdf');
}

function foo(qux, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // eval(callback('asdf')); // works
        // eval(baz(callback)); // works
        // eval(qux + "(" + callback + ")"); // resolve is undefined
    });
}

function bar() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            foo('baz', function(response){
                resolve(response);
            });
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}

function init() {
    bar()
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));

}

init();
```

I wrote three examples of different ways to use eval, commented off in the function `foo`
The third example does not work. This is the example I am concerned with as it is how our legacy code works. I know there are other way around this issue. My solution was to just rewrite the function and ***not*** use eval at all.

My question is very precisely, ***why*** does eval lose scope when you pass in the function name as a string, but it does not lose scope when you pass in an actual reference to the same function?

***Here is a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tkcjay4x/6/***

Comment: As tl;dr here: `eval` doesn't "loose scope". It evaluates code in the current scope (direct eval) or in the global (in case of indirect eval).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have to admit, the title scares me a little. If I understand this "black magic", does it make me an evil sorcerer?

When you do `eval(baz(callback))`, `baz` calls `callback`, and `eval` executes the return value of `baz`, which is `undefined`. `eval(undefined)` is equal to `eval('undefined')` which is equal to `undefined`. So in this case using `eval` is essentially no-op – just doing `baz(callback)` would give the same result.

When you do `eval(qux + "(" + callback + ")")`, `qux + "(" + callback + ")"` evaluates to `'baz(function(response){ resolve(response); })'`. When you pass that to eval, the code tries to access a function named `resolve`, which is not present in the current scope. That's why it doesn't work. If you call function directly, it can access variables which were present in the scope in which it was defined, but if you convert a function to a string and pass it to `eval`, it can only access variables from the current scope.

Comment: Yes, yes it does. :)

Comment: agreed. eval is the dark arts. some kind of sith lord practice.